The curse of dimensionality of the Kolmogorov–Arnold neural network
The Kolmogorov–Arnold neural networks (KAN), Ziming Liu et al., KAN: Kolmogorov–Arnold Networks is inspired by the Kolmogorov–Arnold representation theorem (KA theorem). Though it is not proved in the KAN paper, it is shown that by dint of the KA theorem any continuous function can indeed be approximated by KAN.
However, I suspect that the curse of dimensionality is not truly lifted but swept under the rug. Theorem 2.1 of the KAN paper is not equipped to address the curse of dimensionality completely because it stipulates $f(x):=\operatorname{KAN}(x)$ as defined in Equation (2.7) with smooth functions $\Phi_i$'s.
What would be a good formulation of the curse of dimensionality in this milieu? Would the following be one good example?
Question: Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of smooth functions on $R^n$ for all $n\in\mathbf N$. Is there a sequence $(f_i(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n_i})\in \mathcal F)_{i=1}^\infty$ with $n_i$ strictly increasing with respect to $i$ such that
$$\|f_i(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n_i})-\Phi^G_{L-1}\circ \Phi^G_{L-2}\circ\cdots\Phi^G_2\circ\Phi^G_1(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n_i})\|>cG^{\zeta(n_i)}$$
for some increasing function $\zeta(n)$ on the dimension $n$ and some positive constant $c$ and some natural number $L$, where $\Phi^G_i$ is the B-spline approximating functions as defined in Theorem 2.1 of the KAN paper? I suppose we can set $L=2$.
If it is a good formulation, what is the answer to this question?

Should your norm be of $f_n$ minus something, rather than $f$ minus something?  What is $L$?

@LSpice: Thank you for the correction and question. Edited my question including the part regarding $L$.  Please review.

Re, I am confused because I can't see how the left-hand side of "$\lVert f_i - \Phi^G_{L - 1} \circ \Phi^G_{L - 2} \circ \dotsb \circ \Phi^G_2 \circ \Phi^G_1\rVert > c G^{\zeta(n)}$" depends on $n$.  But perhaps it is just me.

@LSpice: $n$ is the dimension of domain of the function $f_i$ and $\Phi^G_{L-1}\circ \Phi^G_{L-2}\circ\cdots\Phi^G_2\circ\Phi^G_1$, or that $x\in R^n$. The reason I need $n$ is to examine the error dependence on domain dimension $n$. I welcome suggestions for better notations.

So perhaps $n$ should be $n_i$?  Currently, to the extent that I understand your question, if you can start the sequence with a term $f_1$, then there seems to be nothing preventing you from taking $f_i = f_1$ for all $i$—so what do you gain from asking for a sequence?

@LSpice: Good point. I edited my question accordingly. Please review.

There are multiple problems with the formulation of the question, some perhaps unfixable. First, aren't there hyperparameters of the network such as the size of the hidden layers $n_i$, the residual activation function $b$, the order $k$ of the splines and the number $G$ of intervals? One must specify these and if/how they depend on the dimension.

Second, the answer as stated is obviously yes because you can take any function with nonzero error and simply multiply by a constant to make the error large as desired. One needs a bound on $f$. If you bound only the $L^p$ norm of $f$ for some $p$ then one can choose $f$ to be rapidly oscillating and get the error to be almost equal to the value of $f$ at any point - the same holds for any function approximation scheme with finitely many parameters - so you need a bound for the derivative of $f$ or similar.

You can do something similar if the derivative is controlled by taking $f$ to be very spread out, slowly changing between different functions in an unpredictable way, so one needs to restrict the functions to a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ or else choose a norm on $f$ that sufficiently penalizes spread-out functions. How much is sufficiently depends on which norm is used for the error of the approximation, which you also haven't specified. One has to define a suitable class of functions $f$, and exactly how you let that definition depend on dimension might be decisive.

@WillSawin: You are right. I was weary of prospect of what you stated. What do you think of the KAN paper's claim on lifting the curse dimensionality, particularly in the form/formulation of Theorem 2.1 in the paper? What would be a good formulation that is appropriate to the application of neural networks or the intent of the paper?

@WillSawin: Have you read the KAN paper? How would you formulate the curse-of-dimensionality problem in this milieu?

@Hans I don't know how to formulate it, and it's not clear to me that one can formulate it as a purely formal problem - in some sense it's a claim about what sorts of high-dimensional functions are likely to arise in practice.
